# How to change Edit button view in index page of rails_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I used rails_admin gem in my rails app.
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

I want to change my Edit button view from ".icon-pencil" to something else like bootstrap button.

So how can i change this.I really don't know the rails_admin customization. I think it's little bit hard to customize compare to active_admin gem.

I read doc of rails_admin but not found any solution related this.

[image]

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Theming-and-customization) you can override the CSS in `app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/custom`

Comment: But i want to change button only for 1 page not all.